# Web scrape not pulling back title correctly

Tags: python

I am trying to pull back only the Title from a source code online. My code is able to currently pull all the correct lines, but I cannot figure out how to make it only pull back the title.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup # BeautifulSoup is in bs4 package 
import requests

URL = 'https://sc2replaystats.com/replay/playerStats/10774659/8465' 
content = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(content.text, 'html.parser')
tb = soup.find('table', class_='table table-striped table-condensed')
for link in tb.find_all('tr'):
    name = link.find('td')
    print(name.get_text('title'))
```

I expect it to only say

```
Nexus
Pylon
Gateway
Assimilator
ect
```

but I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 11, in <module>
    print(name.get_text().strip())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong since from what I read it should only pull back the desired results

Comment: Do you get any results at all? Or does it error right away?

Comment: I don't get any results the error listed above is the only response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code. Your first row had table header instead of table data so it will be none when you are looking for the `td` tag.

So add the condition to check when you can find either `td` or `span` inside `td` tag then get its title as below.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup # BeautifulSoup is in bs4 package 
import requests

URL = 'https://sc2replaystats.com/replay/playerStats/10774659/8465' 
content = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(content.text, 'html.parser')
tb = soup.find('table', class_='table table-striped table-condensed')
for link in tb.find_all('tr'):
    name = link.find('span')
    if name is not None:
        # Process only if the element is available
        print(name['title'])
```

Comment: This is what I was going to get to in my comment above. You have to be careful when you try to access elements that may not exist. So whether that's through an if statement as @bkyada used above, or a try/catch block, you should make sure to cover your bases in terms of errors.

Answer (score 0):

I thinkg you should use something like

`for link in tb.find_all('tr'):
    name = link.select('td[title]')
    print(name.get_text('title'))`

Because until I see, the string comes empty because there are not title tag name, so you are trying to get text from title attr from the tag td

Answer (score 0):

**bkyada's** answer is perfect if you want another solution then.

In your for loop instead of finding `td` find_all `span` and iterate through it and find it's title attribute.

```
containers = link.find('span')
if  containers is not None:
  print(containers['title'])
```

Answer (score 0):

It is more efficient to simply use the class name to identify the elements with `title` attribute as they all have one in first column.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup # BeautifulSoup is in bs4 package 
import requests

URL = 'https://sc2replaystats.com/replay/playerStats/10774659/8465' 
content = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(content.text, 'html.parser')
tb = soup.find('table', class_='table table-striped table-condensed')
titles = [i['title'] for i in tb.select('.blizzard_icons_single')]
print(titles)
titles = {i['title'] for i in tb.select('.blizzard_icons_single')}  #set of unique
print(titles)
```

As `title` attribute is limited to that column you could also have used (slighlty less quick) attribute selector:

```
titles = {i['title'] for i in tb.select('[title]')}  #set of unique
```